# How i can convert SVG to CSS gradient?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG icon and would like to convert it to a CSS gradient. Do you know of any free resources where this can be done? Thank you!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to create a CSS gradient from SVG, just use some program to compile. For example javier.xyz/img2css here i can convert SVG to CSS (box-shadow). Need something like that but to convert it to CSS GRADIENT. Thanks!

Comment: The [superuser stackexchange](https://superuser.com/) would probably be a better place for this question, though I'm not quite sure it fits there either. For these kinds of questions Google would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

First get your SVG into the browser and use an eyedropper tool addon or import it to illustrator and eye dropper the colors you want. Then with those hex codes you can make any kind of gradient you want.

Learn about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/codingcrafter/zepchr1k/5/

In the w3 schools link, it can show you how you can have multiple gradients, gradients coming from different directions (using a circle in degrees) etc etc.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, #9fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
}

p.boring-p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
  align-self: center;
}

<div class="container">
  <p class="boring-p">Some really boring text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to create a gradient myself, just use some program to compile. For example https://javier.xyz/img2css/ here i can convert SVG to CSS (box-shadow). Need something like that but to convert it to CSS GRADIENT. Thanks!